# Error 400 Invalid request YII for deleting a record

Tags: post, yii, delete-row

I am trying to delete a record in Yii, which throws a Error 400. Please do not repeat this request again. It's checking for a post variable, my controller file has 
 `if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)` 
  When I echo my post variable it's blank whereas $_GET has the id which I want to delete, my View file looks like,

```
echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode('Delete image'), array('image/delete', 'id'=>$image->id), array('class' => 'delete','confirm'=>'This will remove the image. Are you sure?'));
```

The access rules has delete to authenticated users, which is right. Tried it with a * too.
I also tried sending it as a hidden variable but no good.

Not able to figure out how should I post a form in Yii.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is happening because it's not a post request. `CHtml::link` has a way by which you can use post method, instead of get. This requires you to use `submit` attribute of [`clientChange`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#clientChange-detail), in your `htmlOptions`.

Somewhat like this:

```php
echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode('Delete image'), array('image/delete', 'id'=>$image->id),
  array(
    'submit'=>array('image/delete', 'id'=>$image->id),
    'class' => 'delete','confirm'=>'This will remove the image. Are you sure?'
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks.. It worked. :) So, all defaults are 'Get' in Yii, right? Wheneer, I need to post a form, i explicitly need to define it, the way you showed it?

Comment: by default, links are supposed to be 'Get' always, be it yii or simple html. but yes when we need to post through a link, this is the way in yii, it attaches a small javascript line to the output, which submits the form. but if you are talking about full fledged forms, take a look at cactiveform.

Comment: I'm not able to implement this, can someone please check my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014436/error-400-invalid-request-when-creating-custom-delete-button-in-cgridview

Answer (score 10):

the default with Curd will be like this

```
/**
 * @return array action filters
 */
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
        'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
    );
}
```

The delete action can only accessed by POST; You can check it.

So you need to delete this line to work with you 
'postOnly + delete',

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience this caused by some javascript files loaded after jquery.
If you have jQuery link at the end of the document please remove it.

Comment: The build-in JQuery was indeed my problem. I have disabled it by following this: http://hatadu.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/how-to-use-your-own-jquery-library-in-yii/

Answer (score 0):

I think your actionDelete() contains the code that throws this, and I guess it depends on AJAX call or not. Check your relevant actionDelete()